# Google Calendar API problems with attendes and conferenceData

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, service-accounts, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to create a video call in  google calendar but the ConferenceData data arrives empty because none has been created, also when I add participants I get the error: The service calendar has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority. But I have added the service account id to the domain in google Workspace.

Otherwise it works correctly, the calendar is created when I don't add attendees due to the exception produced by the API.

```
  Public Function createMeeting(meetInfo As Meetinfo) As IHttpActionResult
            Try
                ' Se obtienen las credenciales iniciando sesion automaticamente con el usuario establecido

                Dim credential As GoogleCredential = GetCredentials()

                ' Se crea el servicio de Google Calendar
                Dim calendarService As New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential, .ApplicationName = "xxxx"})

                ' Creamos el evento de Google Calendar con la reunión de meet

                Dim meetingEvent As New [Event] With {
                .Summary = meetInfo.meetingTitle,
                .Location = "Google Meet",
                .Description = meetInfo.meetingDescription,
                .ConferenceData = New ConferenceData() With {
                .CreateRequest = New CreateConferenceRequest() With {
                    .RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                    }
                },
                .AnyoneCanAddSelf = True
                }

                Dim startTime As New EventDateTime()
                startTime.DateTime = meetInfo.meetingDate

                Dim endTime As New EventDateTime()
                endTime.DateTime = meetInfo.meetingDate.AddHours(1)

                meetingEvent.Start = startTime
                meetingEvent.End = endTime

                ' Añadimos los participantes
                Dim attendeesList As New List(Of EventAttendee)()

                For Each attendee As String In meetInfo.attendees
                    Dim attendeeObject As New EventAttendee()
                    attendeeObject.Email = attendee

                    attendeesList.Add(attendeeObject)
                Next

                meetingEvent.Attendees = attendeesList

                ' Insertamos el evento en Google Calendar.
                Dim calendarId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("meetCalendarId")
                Dim request As EventsResource.InsertRequest = calendarService.Events.Insert(meetingEvent, calendarId)
                request.ConferenceDataVersion = 1
                'request.SendNotifications = True

                Dim result As [Event] = request.Execute()

                ' Recuperamos el link de la reunión de meets
                Dim meetLink As String = Nothing
                If result.ConferenceData IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each entryPoint In result.ConferenceData.EntryPoints
                        If entryPoint.EntryPointType = "video" Then
                            meetLink = entryPoint.Uri
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

                Return Ok(meetLink)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Return InternalServerError(ex)
            End Try
        End Function
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpCMf.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpKWP.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgU1B.png)

Comment: Please translate your question to English.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't set up domain-wide delegation: https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106

Comment: The system administrator added domain-wide delegation as seen in the third picture with the service account id, it appears in the first line and I don't know if any additional configuration is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured domain wide delegation. You need to remember to use Create with user to denote the user who you want to impersonate when you are making the call.

```
Using stream = New FileStream(keyfilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(Scopes).CreateWithUser("mail@domain.com")
        End Using
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much Linda